# Load react google map component after receive locations data from API

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have `react-redux` thats handling the fetch of locations data from an API, and it works well (console shows loc state filled in redux). If I `console.log` locations in Map.js first it shows `undefined` and later it shows data. Because of this, I cannot load markers on the map as Google map tries to load it immediately, I suppose. So the question is how to make google maps load the markers or the complete component when markers (from the API) are fetched?

I am trying to use hooks and functional component to load map. I tried to use `useEffect` but I don't know how to do it. 'noob'

```
let Map = ({ loc }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loc) etchLoc();
}[]);

return (
 <GoogleMap ...>
    <MarkerCluser>
       {loc.map((item, index) => (
            <Marker ... />
       )}
    </MarkerCluser>
     )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood question well. You could use slightly different approach, smoe thing like this:

```
let marker = "";
    if (loc !== null) {
        marker = locations.map((m, index) => (<Marker ... />
```

and then in map use `{marker}`

I assume that loc in state is set to null...

Hope that helps.

Comment: managet do pull it on this approach, I also changed code so it worked. Thx